# Variadic template ambiguity - empty parameter pack

Tags: c++

How can I remove the ambiguity of this code ? ([Try it here](https://godbolt.org/z/aLAfvg))

```
template <typename T>
inline void f()
{   
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
inline void f()     
{
    f<Args...>();
}

int main() 
{
    f<char, double, int>();     

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the solution i found ... but I'm not really satisfied with it. ([Try it here](https://godbolt.org/z/_o-K-y))

```
template <int N>
inline void f()
{ 
}

template<int N, typename T, typename ... Args>
inline void f()     
{
    f<42,Args...>();
}

int main() 
{
    f<42,char, double, int>();     

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to give a template specialization for an empty parameter pack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specialized `f` at all! You've overloaded it. That is, you have two templates under the name `f`, and it is ambiguous which one you want to use. Consider the call `f<int>()`. Do you mean to instantiate the first template with `T = int`, or the second with `T = int; Args = {}`? If you want to properly specialize `f`, I think it actually needs to be wrapped into a class (to allow partial specialization):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct f_wrapper
{
    static inline void f()
    {
        f_wrapper<Args...>::f();
    }
};
```

Then you can use this syntax to specialize it:

```
template<typename T>
// the brackets v v distinguish specialization from overloading
// you can't overload classes anyway, but it's important for functions
struct f_wrapper<T>
{
    static inline void f()
    {
    }
};
```

Now, there is one class template named `f`, which has two specializations. There is no ambiguity in `f_wrapper<int>::f()`. The one and only template is instantiated with `T = int; Args = {}`, and then this is used to choose the `Args = {}` specialization (the second definition).

You can then proceed to wrap this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline void f() { f_wrapper<T, Args...>::f(); }
```

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is add an another template parameter to the variadic overload like

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
inline void f()     
{
    f<U, Args...>();
}
```

This meas the function can only be called with 2 or more parameters so there is no more ambiguity between a single parameter or a single parameter and empty pack.

---

Depending on what you want to achieve in the function you might also be able to switch to using a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) if you can use C++17

Comment: You're right, it's smarter than using a dummy int argument ! Thanks !