# Why is the `count()` function overload in `fmt/core.h` implemented like this?

Tags: c++, fmt

In `fmt/core.h`, I noticed the function `count_named_args()` which uses the template function `count` with a given predicate.

And I found the overloaded version for `count` version is weird:

```cpp
template <bool B1, bool B2, bool... Tail> constexpr auto count() -> size_t {
  return (B1 ? 1 : 0) + count<B2, Tail...>();
}
```

why do we need to take a template parameter `bool B2` to extract the next boolean value explicitly, and not the parameter pack `bool... Tail` directly?

If I remove the `bool B2` stuff, and try compile:

```cpp
template <bool B1, bool... Tail> constexpr auto count() -> size_t {
  return (B1 ? 1 : 0) + count<Tail...>();
}
```

```cpp
static_assert(count<false>() == 0);
static_assert(count<true, false>() == 1);
```

It gives an error as it is ambiguous to determine the overload when the parameter number reduces to the last one:

```cpp
size_t count<false,>(void) noexcept
size_t count<false>(void) noexcept
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. Although there are other ways to avoid the ambiguity you found, most of the others are more complex, verbose, or require newer features (fold expressions, which aren't available until C++17).

Comment: Hi Jerry, I know it's quite easy to write a fold expression to sum a pack. The key of this question is I want to know why the extra `B2` parameter helps solve the ambiguous problem? Does it make the second overload accepts all the calls with more than 1 parameter and hence solve it?

Comment: Yes, when you get to a single template parameter, it's ambiguous whether you want a parameter by itself, or a single parameter plus an empty parameter pack. With two named parameters, that choice never arises. Perhaps the answers to this earlier (near dupe) question explain it better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56062683/179910

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the current main](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/5cfd28d476c6859617878f951931b8ce7d36b9df/include/fmt/core.h#L1216), there are two function templates:

```
template <bool B = false> constexpr auto count() -> size_t { return B ? 1 : 0; }
template <bool B1, bool B2, bool... Tail> constexpr auto count() -> size_t {
  return (B1 ? 1 : 0) + count<B2, Tail...>();
}
```

If those were instead

```
template <bool B = false> constexpr auto count() -> size_t { return B ? 1 : 0; }
template <bool B1, bool... Tail> constexpr auto count() -> size_t {
  return (B1 ? 1 : 0) + count<Tail...>();
}
```

then for call `count<false>()`, both candidates are considered and as per overload resolution rules neither is more specialized than the other -> ambiguity. Remember, parameter packs can be empty. Why is having an extra parameter pack not considered less specialized, that I honestly do not know.

Only having `<bool B1, bool... Tail>` would not work for zero arguments and having extra non-template `count` for this case would not work for corner cases of `count<pack...>()` and `pack` being empty. On the other hand `<bool B = false>` can still be called like `count()` thanks to the default value.

I think `<bool B = false>` and `<bool B1, bool B2, bool... Tail>` is the most generic and simplest solution.